Definition of irreducibilty of Algebraic (or Deligne-Mumford) Stacks
I am trying to understand the definition of irreducible stack.
In the paper "the irreducibility of the space of curves of given genus" by Deligne-Mumford, it says that

But I don't understand how the union of substacks is defined.
In stacks project (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DR4) and Definition 3.3.20 in "Stacks and Moduli (2024)" by Jarod Alper (https://sites.math.washington.edu/~jarod/moduli.pdf), it says that the stacks is irreducible if the underlying topological space (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04XE) is irreducible.
Are these definitions equivalent?
